# How do i hide a layer from layerlist in ArcGIS 4.x Javascript API though i still want it to show up in the map?

Tags: gis, legend, arcgis-js-api

I would like to remove Facilities in the layerlist, but still have it show up in the map.

[image]

```
var manned_facilities_back = new MapImageLayer({
    url: "http://dotdevgisiis02:6080/arcgis/rest/services/DOT_MAP_PORTAL/Facilities/MapServer",

    sublayers: [
    {
      id: 1, 
      popupTemplate: templateFT,


    },
    {
      id: 0,
      popupTemplate: templateMF,

    },


    ]
```

I've attempted to add

```
 listmode: hide
```

or

```
display: none
```

under where i have url, but it didn't work. I figure this should be really simple.

Answer (score 1):

Setting the property [`Layer.listMode`](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-layers-Layer.html#listMode) to `"hide"` should work as expected. In your example, make sure you use the correct casing:

```
var layer = new MapImageLayer({
  url: "http://dotdevgisiis02:6080/arcgis/rest/services/DOT_MAP_PORTAL/Facilities/MapServer",
  listMode: "hide"
});
```

Here's a live demo hiding one of the layers from the loaded WebScene:
https://codepen.io/arnofiva/pen/eb198c9b4050b892759ef433e8664fac